# Python\SQL\CSV обработка файла

Tags: python, sql, csv

Есть огромный CSV файл. Сейчас работаю с ним через Pandas (примеры ниже).

Можно ли обращаться к CSV файлу используя SQL запросы, если нет БД на компьютере, и если да, то как?

```
data = pd.read_csv('Data/2021-03-06.csv', delimiter=';')
data.groupby('information').size()
```

Comment: При работе с Dataframe, а именно его возвращает read_csv, можно использовать любые свойства реляционной алгебры, методы описаны в документации https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html. Чистый sql, разумеется писать нельзя

Comment: Ну там есть `query`, MaxU любит через него запросы делать, это некое подобие `sql` или `linq`. И всё же вопрос не совсем понятен - что именно вы хотите - делать `groupby` не в функциональном виде, а подобно `sql` запросу чтобы выглядело?

Comment: Учти, что практически каждый запрос должен будет заново прочитать весь CSV (если он действительно огромный и не лезет в ОЗУ) - и соответственно обработать. так что работать будет... скажем так - неспешно.

Comment: @Akina, в коде, приведенном в вопросе, используется Pandas для чтения CSV файла в DataFrame. DataFrame хранится в памяти, поэтому можно делать разные запросы, прочитав CSV файл один раз в DataFrame

Comment: @MaxU Вот зачем писать. что "DataFrame хранится в памяти" в ответ на комментарий со словами "если он действительно огромный и не лезет в ОЗУ"?

Comment: @Akina, "Keep Calm and Carry On" ;)

Answer (score 2):

В классическом Pandas можно имитировать только `WHERE clause` из SQL, используя метод [DataFrame.query()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
id_list = [1,2,3]
df.query("col1 < 12 and id in @id_list")
```

Если же нужно большее - группировки и агрегация, более сложные условия и т.д. то можно попробовать [pandasql](https://pypi.org/project/pandasql/) (последний релиз - апрель 2016).

Если возможностей `pandasql` не хватит, тогда можно воспользоваться [Apache Spark SQL](https://spark.apache.org/sql/), который полностью поддерживает ANSI SQL Standard.

NOTE: установка и настройка Apache Spark кластера может оказаться непростой процедурой для неопытного пользователя.